# Custom B2C Login Page with Additional Fields

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, azure-ad-b2c

We have a B2C local login with a signinorup user flow.  We also have an API connector set to add additional claims in our token.

We have a need for an additional field on the login screen that the user can enter text into and have this field sent to the API connector.  Actually I don't care if its on the same login screen or an additional screen but when they login using their local B2C account we need this field in the API connector.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a custom policy in B2C, that can capture this additional field via UI, you need to make use of `technical profile` in your custom policy. Thus captured field generally exposed as a `claim`.

Refer this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/self-asserted-technical-profile).